# Display variable from async function in Ionic Template

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework, async-await, vue-component, vuejs3

I'm trying to display a result from an `async` method in the Vue/Ionic Template. I successfully retrieve the value from the local storage and output it using `console.log`

```
 setup() {

 import {Plugins} from "@capacitor/core";
 const {Storage}=Plugins;

 const getEmail= async()=>{
          const emailv=await Storage.get({key: "email"});
          console.log(emailv.value);
          return emailv.value;
    };


 }
```

I also tried this

```
 setup() {

  import {Plugins} from "@capacitor/core";
  const {Storage}=Plugins;

   const emailv= async()=>{
          const {value}=await Storage.get({key: "email"});
          console.log(value);
          return value;
    };
}
```

And that's how I call it on my template:

```
<ion-note>{{emailv()}}</ion-note>
```

The problem is that, although it's being successfully displayed on the console, it doesn't seem to work on the template. It just shows me `"[object Promise]"`. I have tried looking for some solutions and, from what I understood (please correct me if I'm wrong as I'm not sure how async-await works.), once I retrieve the variable, I should be able to use it everywhere.

**So my question is:**

Is there any way for me to "get" this variable and display it in the template?

Comment: please share the whole code that includes this function

Comment: Thank you. I will update my question but there's nothing much to show actually. I'm using imports. It works, It just doesn't display the value correctly.

Comment: are you using this in setup hook?

Comment: Yes. I'm using it in setup hook.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this ? Put your setup async and await the result in your const :

```
async setup() {
  const emailv = await getResults()

  function getResults() {
    return Storage.get({key: "email"})
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call that function inside the mounted hook then just use `emailv` in your template :

```
import {ref,onMounted} from 'vue';
 import {Plugins} from "@capacitor/core";
 const {Storage}=Plugin

export default{

setup(props){
  const emailv=ref('')

  onMounted( async ()=>{
     const {value}=await Storage.get({key: "email"});

     emailv.value=value;
   })

  return{
   emailv
  }
}
}
```

template :

```
<ion-note>{{emailv}}</ion-note>
```

Comment: `120:5  error  'onMounted' is not defined  no-undef`

Comment: did you add `import {ref,onMounted} from 'vue';`?

Comment: I just did, thank you. It console.logs the value but doesn't display anything on the template. Now it shows nothing.

Comment: If I try to display a text in a normal function it works.

Comment: No. It shows the value, but on the template It either displays "[object Promise]" or shows nothing. If I try to do the same thing in a normak function it works, the problem is that storage needs async to work.

Comment: could you share the output of `console.log(emailv.value);` after `emailv.value=value;`

Comment: https://snipboard.io/jQtMhi.jpg the email on the console should be displayed under "Inbox"

Comment: what about `onMounted( ()=>{  Storage.get({key: "email"}).then(res=> emailv.value=res.value;}) })`?

Comment: It keeps showing nothing. When I use then, it shows nothing, when I use async, it shows me "[object Promise]". The only warning I get is: `"Property "emailv" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance."`